# Brackets and Special char used in AngularJS 2 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, special-characters, angular

I am now learning angularjs2 after angularjs1. I am using TypeScript variation. I found some brackets and special characters are being used for angular attributes. Can any one please help me to understand in depth which one is used for what reason with proper example. Also please add any more special char related to this question (if I missed any.)

```
[(ngModel)]

(click)

*ngIf

ngRepeat="#hero in heros"
```

Etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [(ngModel)] :

Normally we used this syntax for `TWO WAY BINDING` in the Angular2. i.e either we made changes from template or from controller
it angular reflects changes. normally we used this syntax if we have to make changed both side at the same side in the template as well as controller.

## (click):

this is is event binding in the Angular2. there are a lot of event bindings are there in the Angular2.

## *ngIf :

this syntax is juts like `display: none/block` in the css. but it is different from css's selector `display` as according to Angular2's *ngIf does't allow to render
the portion of code which is false i.e if `*ngIf='false'` on any div or any html part. angular does't allow to render that portion. whereas in CSS that portion occupy a space.

## ngRepeat="#hero in heros"

this is angular 1.x's syntax but in the angular2 `ngRepeat` is replaced with `*ngFor`. normaly we used `*ngFor` for iterate over array to get all items from the array of list to avoid
extra code. here *ngFor in the angular2 comnined with two variables like here...

```
*ngFor= '#hero of Heros'
```

here `#hero` is a local variable and Heros is the name of array over whihc we iterate a loop.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @PardeepJain s answer.

```
<my-comp [(someName)]="someExpression">
```

is the short form of

```
<my-comp [someName]="someExpression" (someNameChange)="someExpression=$event">
```

where in `MyComp` there has to be an `input` and an `output` like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  inputs: ['someName'],
  outputs: ['someNameChange']})
class MyComp {
  someName:SomeType;
  someNameChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

or alternatively like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp'
})
class MyComp {
  @Input() someName:SomeType;
  @Output() someNameChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

- Input: see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html
- Output: see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html

This works the same for directives.